# How to raise event in javascript when server calls client?

Tags: javascript, signalr

Hub has the following method:

```
public bool SendMessage(MessageModel model)
{
    this.Clients.Group(model.RoomName).sendClientMessage(model);
    return true;
}
```

and on the client:

```
function hubService(connection) {       
    var myHub = connection.chat;
    myHub.client.sendClientMessage = function (messageModel) {       
        return messageModel;
    };
}
```

What I want is to allow other javascript objects that take in `hubService` as a dependency to subscribe to `sendClientMessage` function so that when the server calls `sendClientMessage` all the subscribers will be sent the `messageModel`.  This is pretty easy to define in c#, but not sure how to do this in javascript.

Comment: `function(messageModel) {}` is a callback, `return`ing `messageModel` probably isn't what you want to do there...

Comment: the client end should have a subscriber that comes with it, on(), addEventListener(), etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`window.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent), but I'd recommend using a custom event-emitter instead. Like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-emitter) on npm.